# Is it possible to connect miband2 and arduino nano (?)

Tags: arduino-nano, bluetooth, iot

I want to make an IOT project using an Arduino nano and I need heart rate sensors. I I have a miband2. So, is it possible to connect them ?

Comment: First find out what communication protocol the miband2 uses.

Comment: Mi band use BLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect as a central device.
I've had good luck with the adafruit nrf52 feather.  Also see: https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge for the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

To use BLE on Arduino, I tried google and found this [Article](https://developex.com/blog/best-modules-shields-and-boards-for-ble-usage-on-arduino/):

Examples:

- HM-10 (HM-11) BLE Module
- BLE Nano
- BLE Mini
- BLE Shield v2.1
- RFduino
- Bluno series
- BLE WT51822-ABS
- Grove – BLE
- BLEduino

Chose one that fits best, and use it.